# How to stop Facebook and Linked in Api keys and secrets from being exposed?

Tags: jquery, knockout.js, client-side

We are writing client side code using Knockout.js and have applications settings represented in Json.

We have an authentication feature that allows people to log in using their Facebook and LinkedIn accounts.

Our app secrets, id's and keys are being rendered server side and stored client side as mentioned above.

This Json is available for anyone using our site to see when they view the page source.

ex.

```
{
  FacebookAppId: "xxxxxxxxx",
  FacebookSecret: "xxxxxxxxx",
  LinkedInKey: "xxxxxxxxx",
  LinkedInSecret: "xxxxxxxxx"
};
```

Is it at all possible to stop showing these values on page source?

I have considered obfuscation but I'd like to consider something better than that.

Comment: If you're sending the data to the client, they have it. You can implement the log-in feature without client-side.

Comment: Usually this would remain server-side.. what are you using for server-side logic?